# Very slow machine and with no connection after update on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I am mostly looking for **advice on how to investigate these kind of problems on my own**, because they seem to be recurrent.

I updated a Ubuntu 20.04 machine (with simple `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade`), and after reboot, I encountered multiple problems. I don't know if they are all linked.

Here are the packages updated:

```
apparmor ca-certificates gamemode gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
  gir1.2-nm-1.0 gnome-desktop3-data gnome-logs libapparmor1
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgamemode0 libgamemodeauto0
  libgnome-desktop-3-19 liblilv-0-0 libnm0 libwinpr2-2 network-manager
  network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu xserver-common xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-legacy xwayland
```

After a reboot, I can still access Ubuntu but:

1. I can't access the TTY command-lines.
2. On the login screen, my keyboard settings (French keyboard) don't seem to be loaded, and it defaults back to a qwerty setting (but after login, my azerty works OK).
3. Once logged in, the interface is extremely slow (for example, going back from a non-working TTY-1 to the graphical session, it takes approximately 10 minutes). The only graphic app I could launch there is a GNOME Terminal, and even in there, I can't get the result of a single small command.
4. There is no icon showing my Ethernet connection.

I could just reinstall, but I already did it last week (on this machine and another!) after another `apt upgrade` causing problems without being able to investigate properly, and its getting tiring.

**How should I investigate/fix these kind of post-upgrade problems?**

---

After booting in recovery/root (the only way I could find to access a working command line):

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Gtraphics 520] (rev 07)
        Subsytem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Gtraphics 520]
        Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
```

Comment: Asking one question about "many problems" is discouraged at this site. Please [edit] your question and leave one question that can be answered.

Comment: I could remove the part about the first machine. But for the second one, all these "many problems" result from a single action, so I can't be sure that they are not linked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Done. I removed the comment about Nvidia which was only for the other machine (sorry about that).

Comment: Almost a similar problem occurred with me also, which was caused due to messing around with some important files. Did you mess around with the OS before the upgrade, such as editing files inside `/etc` folder?

Comment: It is a very recent install, and apart from update/upgrade/install of apps, I only edited `/etc/fstab` to automount my secondary HDD, and `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` to remove Nautilus default favorites (as I have done for a while in my Ubuntu installs). Moreover, these `/etc/...` occured a few days ago, and the problems only started after this morning's update.